# Django cms get content variable in parent template

Tags: django, django-cms

Say I have a content plugin that adds a variable `{{ category }}` to the plugin's context.

The plugin can be rendered zero or numerous times within a placeholder. I don't care which variable I retrieve, but I want to access it from the parent template, e.g.

**plugin.html**

```
<div class="widget">
    {{ category }}
</div>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<h1>{{ category }}</h1>  <!-- I want the optional variable here -->
<div class="main">
    {% placeholder content %}
</div>
```

I know feincms uses a template tag called "fragment" which can append and check variables within the request object, but it seems django-cms has no such system, so what is the proper way to do this?

I have tried to add it to the session within the plugin;

```
def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    ...
    request = context['request']
    request.session['category'] = instance.category
    ...
```

This works but only after refreshing the page, else the variable is "one page behind"...

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it in allmost every template, maybe create your own context processor and add it to `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

```
# yourapp.filename.py
def context_processor(request):
    category = ...
    return {
        "category": category,
    }
```

And add the following line to `settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

```
yourapp.filename.context_processor
```